# How do you edit out wind?

Tags: outdoors, wind, editing, spectrum, techniques

I'm using a Sony MZ-M10 with the stock mic, and a sock wrapped around it (not much wind protection). I just recorded the recycling truck making its rounds, but the wind blew just before it drove off. I loaded it up on soundtrack pro to edit, but it hit me; I don't know how to take the wind out while keeping the it all balanced.

[soundcloud]rodshields/recycling-truck[/soundcloud]

Answer (score 4):

Well, some wind noise you can't just get rid of, but I'd start with EQ.  Most wind noise is in the lower frequencies, so try an HPF and such.

You might also try Izotope RX.  It has a few tools, such as spectral repair and noise reduction that might help you out a bit as well.

Depending on how bad your wind noise is, you might try a multiband expander, if you have access to one.

My last suggestion would be a Cedar unit.  Also not something that a lot of people have access to, but if you do, it could be a big help!

Good Luck!

Comment: Agree with all of this, especially the Cedar plugin; truly excellent!

Answer (score 2):

That's the bummer with most portable recorders. I have a Sony PCM D-1 with a wind furry which I carry around for the odd recording and I often struggle with wind distortion.

A low cut EQ set somewhere around 60-200hz can often remove wind distortion. Often I'll just automate the eq so it's only on during the points where the distortion occurs. That way I'm not taking the low end out of the entire recording. Of course, you can also just edit those points out too.

Using a multiband compressor or a Cedar DNS can also do wonders.

Comment: It'll be a while until I have Cedar money. I'm saving for a Zoom H4N right now, and it looks like I'll have to add the Izotope RX to the list too. I'm going to use to eq on it, and see how it works out. Thanks

Comment: I've been getting very usable results from a combination of a Zoom H4 and Izotope RX for a few years now. Definitely worth getting a more serious form of wind protection (some of the Rycote Mini Windjammers fit portable recorders).

Alternatively, get a more serious mic with wind protection to match and simply use the portable recorder to record the output.

Answer (score 1):

It's a too late now, but in the future - it's better to turn on HP-filter on your recording device or mic if it possible - very helps against wind while recording

Comment: does it really?  is there a difference between an HP filter on my field equipment, or just doing it in post?

Comment: Yes, it will prevent sub-low loud wind signal in your record. It's the same as if you'll record very loud - you can't return signal from it's clipped condition just with rising volume down in post

Comment: As I found out in recording room tones, in omni, a rolloff is almost a must (that is, if you're not going for getting the sub bass of course)

Answer (score 0):

If the sound disappears completely from wind pushing in the mic diaphragm there's not much you can do afterwards. Always work on getting the best source material right away. Do some tests with your equipment before hand.