# Removing blow sound in post production

Tags: post-production

I am supposed to mix a song in Dolby digital.I wasn't there for the recording session and unfortunately the track is full of blows.I am using Nuendo 4 for the final mix.Is there any way to remove the blows.I have got a wave lab as plugins.

Comment: @Chris Sorry, What do you mean by blows?

Comment: wind noise is incredibly hard to remove. good luck.. 

Comment: The closest you can get to this is to roll off all LF below 150Hz on the track that is "blowing" but this will only get you so far. 

Ideal scenario is to send it back into the studio for a vocals re-record with an engineer that actually knows what they are doing.

Answer (score 2):

[How do you edit out wind?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/1391/how-do-you-edit-out-wind)

Answer (score 0):

For "wind" and "pops", use your ear, you'll need to filter out around 150hz and below, but depends on the case!

A good HP filter plugin should do it. If it's on vocals, it's easy to zoom in to the first ms. of a word, and you'll "see" the wind distortion. See if you can just apply the filter to that first section without filtering out the whole track, that way you get to keep some of the vocal's body. 
You might experience clicks after applying the filter in such a way: try to select the waveform in a way where a whole cycle is selected: that should help with the clicks.

Mind me asking why you're "mixing in Dolby"?